# how to set alarm following weekly in android studio

Tags: android

when i set alarm following weekly its not work , i already tied many way but not one is success  Here my code..

```
public void forday(int week, int hour, int minuts, int position, int formate) {

        Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar  now=Calendar.getInstance();

        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,week);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
        calSet.set(Calendar.AM_PM, formate);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        if (calSet.before(Calendar.getInstance())){
             calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,7);
        }

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        int pos = position + week + 1028;
        intent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, pos, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line of code

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

with

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

There is also a simple way to schedule an alarm weekly using `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

Adding working code snipped below, for testing purpose setting alarm for 2 minute after current time.

```
        Calendar next = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int nowWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int nowMinute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int nowDay = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int nowFormat = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        next.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, nowWeek);
        next.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, nowDay);
        next.set(Calendar.MINUTE, nowMinute + 2);
        next.set(Calendar.AM_PM, nowFormat);
        next.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (now.after(next)) {
            // Added a day
            next.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, next.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: i tried but alarm is not fired , like  today is Wednesday now i set alarm Thursday 12:3 am but alarm is not fired, please suggest me..

Comment: @jaber share the changes you tested for? I can run my end too and confirm accordingly. for testing purpose we can schedule alarm for 2 or 5 min.

Comment: share your manifest file too. Code is incomplete, will hard to run. I don't want to create separate app to just verify. Please share the entire app if it has not sensitive data

Comment: @jaber have added working code snipped in answer post, do review and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: now i uploaded full project please see the full project and sagest me.
https://github.com/JaberAhamed/alarmClock