# Android set AlarmManager to notification 1 day before real day from calenda not work

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to set alarm notification 1 day before real day from calenda.

This is my code.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put(DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, vt);
                        cv.put(DBHelper.COL_DATE, mDisplayDate.getText().toString());

                        db.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id = ?",new String[]{rowId});
                        cursor.requery();

                        String[] parts = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().split("-");
                        String day = parts[0];
                        String month = parts[1];
                        String year = parts[2];
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(day)-1);  //1-31
                        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(month));  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
                        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year));//year...

                        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);  //HOUR
                        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);       //MIN
                        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);       //SEC

                        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        myIntent = new Intent(DriverLicenseActivity.this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DriverLicenseActivity.this, 0,myIntent , 0);
                        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);


                        getData();


                    }
                })
```

I set calenda before real day by using Integer.parseInt(day)-1 like this.

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(day)-1);
```

But when I run code to time 23.20 it not show anything. Not have Notification from android.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849117/how-to-set-alarm-following-weekly-in-android-studio/51850212#51850212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you wrote that the value for DAY_OF_YEAR is (1-31). Then you set DAY_OF_YEAR using that value minus 1 (so 0-30).

If you read the documentation for `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` you will note that it is the day number within the YEAR (not within the MONTH) and the first day of the year is 1 (not 0). So DAY_OF_YEAR has the value (1-366).

Also, you should always set Calendar values from largest to smallest. So you should set YEAR, then MONTH and then DAY_OF_MONTH (which has values 1-31).

---

NOTE: When having problems with Calendar, it is useful to output the date that you think is in the Calendar to make sure that it is really the date that you wanted to set. You can do that using something like this:
    String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.v("tag","Date is " + formattedDate);